# How to display an image inside a div only when hovered the parent div?

Tags: css

```
<div class="spotlight-item width-2 height-2">
    <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
        <h2 class="large">
        Random text
        </h2>
    </a>

    <img src="../images/background.jpg"> //actual image

    <a href="#" onClick="alert(111)">      
        <img class="play-button" src="<%THEME%>images/play.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 30%; margin-left: 40%; display: none;">
    </a>
</div>
```

The image with play-button class is set to display: none; by default. However, when user hovers the "spotlight-item" div, play-button image should be set to display: show;

How can I do this?

Comment: $(".spotlight-item").hover(function(){your css})

Comment: Yeah. I want to solve it with pure css though.

Answer (score 2):

```
.spotlight-item:hover .play-button { display: x; }
```

x = inline, block or inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself.

```
/* play button */
.spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item img.play-button {
width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 30%; margin-left: 40%; 
visibility: hidden;

}

/* play button hover */
.spotlight-area .spotlight .spotlight-item:hover img.play-button {
width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 30%; margin-left: 40%; 
visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.spotlight-item       > img { visibility: hidden  }
.spotlight-item:hover > img { visibility: visible }
```

The `visibility` property reserves space for the element even when it isn't visible. This prevents the rendered elements jumping around.

Caveat: Only using `:hover` isn't accessible for pointerless devices.

Comment: Yeah. I've switched to visibility for this reason. What should be used for pointerless devices though?

Comment: That depends. `:focus` is similar to `:hover`, and is triggered when the element has some form of keyboard focus. For touchscreens, you will have to think up some sensible interaction; I have no tips there

Answer (score 0):

Just add some CSS rules. Example:

```
.someClass:hover img {
    display:block;
}
```

This will display all `<img>`'s inside `.someClass` elements.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
.spotlight-item:hover .play-button
{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .play-button {
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px; 
        margin-top: 30%; 
        margin-left: 40%; 
        display: none;
    }
    .spotlight-item:hover .play-button {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div class="spotlight-item width-2 height-2">
    <a href="#" class="spotlight-info">
        <h2 class="large">
        Random text
        </h2>
    </a>

    <img src="../images/background.jpg"> //actual image

    <a href="#" onClick="alert(111)">      
        <img class="play-button" src="<%THEME%>images/play.png">
    </a>
</div>
```